# Get frequency of value in DataFrame column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, crosstab

Part of a homework question I got: I need to get the frequency of a unique value inside a column from a DataFrame, using Pandas. But, I must use `crosstab()` function!

Here is part of the DataFrame

[image]

And I want to get the frequency (in percentage) of the value `'E'` in the `'color'` column.

Here is how the result should look like:

[image]

And this is what I have so far:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? How can I get it the same?

Answer (score -2):

```
pd.crosstab("", dataframe[], normalize=True)
```